# Not found GET /@tests

Tags: playframework

I'm running through the Yabe Tutorial.

I have written a number of the tests and they worked after an amount of tinkering. While running through the tutorial I stopped the Play server, restarted, and when I go to http://localhost:9000/@tests   I see the following...

```
Not found

   GET /@tests
     These routes have been tried, in this order :

    GET       /@documentation/cheatsheet/{category}                 PlayDocumentation.cheatSheet
    GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/files/{name}     PlayDocumentation.file
    GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/images/{name}    PlayDocumentation.image
    GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/{id}             PlayDocumentation.page
    GET       /@documentation/files/{name}                      PlayDocumentation.file
    GET       /@documentation/images/{name}                     PlayDocumentation.image
    GET       /@documentation/{id}                              PlayDocumentation.page
    GET       /@documentation/?                                 PlayDocumentation.index
    GET       /                                                 Application.index
    GET       /favicon.ico                                      404
    GET       /public/                                          staticDir:public
     *         /{controller}/{action}                            {controller}.{action}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you launched the server in test mode? You should run:

```
play test
```